# d3.js x axis date range

Tags: d3.js, graph, graph-visualization

i have some values in my csv file and i show a graph with values on y axis and dates on x axis.

For first graph i have following values

```
date,close
13-Jul-16,0.8736701869033555
15-Jul-16,0.3631761567983922
17-Jul-16,0.4795564555162078
19-Jul-16,0.3754827857186281
21-Jul-16,0.4355941951068847
23-Jul-16,0.34393804366457353
25-Jul-16,0.40967947088135176
27-Jul-16,0.2707818657230363
29-Jul-16,0.34430251610420176
31-Jul-16,0.28089496856221585
```

For second graph i have following values

```
 date,close
 11-Jul-16,0.766705419439816
 15-Jul-16,0.7353651170975812
 17-Jul-16,0.41531502169603063
 19-Jul-16,0.5927871032351933
 21-Jul-16,0.7986419920511857
 23-Jul-16,0.7904979990272231
 25-Jul-16,0.817690401573838
 27-Jul-16,0.8433545168648027
 29-Jul-16,0.8612307965742473
 31-Jul-16,0.806498303188971
```

But in second graph x axis does not contain all dates.. As an example i put a printscreen of my output graphs [myoutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msmRn.png) to here.

This is my code which takes datas from csv file and visualize it.

var selectedMonth=document.getElementById('selectedMonth').value;
    var selectedTopic=document.getElementById('selectedTopic').value;

```
var userFileDirectory="../documents/";

userFileDirectory=userFileDirectory+selectedMonth+"/"+selectedTopic+"/"+"dataCs.csv";



// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;
// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.csv(userFileDirectory, function(error, data) {


    data.forEach(function(d) {

        d.date = parseDate(d.date);

        d.close = +d.close;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));


    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

    svg.append("text")
        .text("("+selectedMonth+" "+selectedTopic+")");


});
```

Comment: Hi - please share the code, especially the parts that establish the scales (domain and range), axis and line function. Also, do both charts use the same scale, axes and line functions?

Comment: @TomShanley thank you for your interest i edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try setting the tick values explicitly, using tickValues:
https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Axes.md#tickValues

ticks(5) will suggest 5 ticks, but will be adapted based on the scale's domain.  Alternative to tickValues(), you could try ticks(d3.time.day, 2) to have a tick every 2 days.

Comment: how can i draw line on a specific point on y axis , i use this but line exists on top of the graph , i want to point out that some points are above average and some are below, or i should find plateu. My aim is to measure threshold Do you have any idea ?                                                               
             svg.append("line")    // attach a line
     .style("stroke", "red")  // colour the line
     .style("stroke-dasharray", ("2,2"))
     .attr("x1", 300)  // x position of the first end of the line
     .attr("y1",0.4 ) ; // y position of the first end of the line